# Optimize the query performance in JPA spring boot

Tags: oracle, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Below is the query used in my repository to get the item results.
But it takes time to return the results may because of join.
What are the tips to improve the performance.

```
@Query( "SELECT new ItemDTO(esb.itemNumber, est.itemDescription) " + 
        "FROM ItemNumTable est, " + 
        "ItemDescTable  esb " + 
        "WHERE est.language = 'US' AND " + 
        "esb.utilizationId = 856756003 AND " + 
        "esb.utilizationId = est.utilizationId AND " + 
        "est.ItemId = esb.ItemId AND " + 
        "UPPER(esb.itemNumber) like UPPER(:itemNum) AND  UPPER(est.itemDescription) like UPPER(:itemDesc) AND ROWNUM <= 100" )
List<ItemNumTable> getItemListbyItemNumAndItemDesc(String itemNum, String itemDesc);
```

Comment: Why are you using ROWNUM and can you please post the code of your entities?

Comment: Why are you tagging this question as "nativequery" when it is not marked as a "native query" (i.e it is JPQL)??? Why haven't you tagged it as "spring-data-jpa" since that is what you are using (not the JPA API)

Comment: Can you post the query as the DBMS sees it (without the Java stuff)? And what are the indexes on the tables and what does the execution plan look like?

Comment: Since I am using like condition, it may returns large no. rows. That's why I am restricting it to return 100 rows

Comment: Hi! There is a lot of possible problems on your query, but it's more probable that the cause of your problem is the lack of some index in one (or more) fields. Per example, if you a big `ItemDescTable` table, you are doing an `upper` on all `itemNumber` on the table. This can be **very** slow. Try to run a query plan with this query on your database to find out the possible causes.